# Placing single line of text centered in its parent in QML

Tags: qt, qml

This task just seems so simple that and still I can not get it to work.

I want to place a single line of text, inside of its parent.

The following should be sufficient as far as I know (and when I read the documentation):

```
Rectangle {
    width: 250
    height: 200
    anchors.top: parent.bottom
    anchors.right: parent.right

    Text {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter

        Text { text: "3"; font.family: "Verdana"; font.pointSize: 13 }
        color: "Black"
    }
}
```

The texts ends up at the top-left corner of its parent:

[image]

What is going on here?
Please don't start suggesting that I should play with anchor and anchorMargin as I really don't see a good reason for using it here. Also the Text is going to change and then it will not be in the middle if I start going that way.

I am using:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
```

Comment: Just remove the nested Text component and assign the text property directly in the outer Text. The layout parameters applied to your outer Text component don't apply on the inner one, which is why the text is not centered but using the default top-left layout.

Comment: @qCring, you are a savior, I did not even see that I was so mad at QT.

Comment: Instead of setting the width and height, it would be easier to just use `anchors.fill: parent`. If you won't need elide or wordwrap, and therfore the size of the text does not matter, you might also use `anchors.centerIn: parent` then you won't need the alignments.